# Looking for sequence of strings through multiple files in directory using R

Tags: r, csv, dataset, corpus

I am writing an R program that reads through CSV files in my directory, searches for strings of characters that I have stored in a vector called `parentVector`, and writes the corresponding row to an output CSV file called `df.csv`. This is what I have so far:

```
setwd("my_directory")

# variable for csv directory
csvFolder <- "csv_directory"

flist <- list.files(path = csvFolder)
masterCorpus <- data.frame()

# This vector gives you the full file list in your directory
allFilesInDirectory <- list.files(csvFolder, full=TRUE)

# This vector will read the data from allFilesInDirectory vector
allTheData <- lapply(allFilesInDirectory, read.csv, header=TRUE)

parentVector <- c("Mother","mother", "Father","father","Adult","adult","MOT","FAT")
```

How do I finish the component of this program to be able to read through each CSV file in my directory and searches for the strings contained in the parentVector?

Comment: Unclear what is meant by: "look through each CSV file and look for the strings contained in the parentVector?\."

Comment: The comments sound a bit like this is a homework assignment.  If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: This isn't for homework. I've got a small job as an R programmer and I've been getting acquainted with the language. The comments are for readability

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very quickly using the [stringr package](http://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html)

Once you have the csv read into a data frame, you can test whether a row contains any of the strings in the parentVector character vector by creating a regex for each of those elements separated by "|" the OR regex operator.  You can do this quickly with `paste0`, shown below.  Then use that as the regex you pass as the pattern argument to stringr's `str_detect`.  So if you have a csv read into a variable called df, it would look like:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

parent_vector_pattern <- paste0(parentVector, collapse="|")

filtered_df <- df %>%
    mutate(contains_pattern = str_detect(COLUMN_WITH_TEXT_NAME_HERE, parent_vector_pattern) %>%
    filter(contains_pattern)
```

Please note that the mutate, filter, and %>% are apart of the dplyr package.